# Is lack of User-Agent in HTTP request valid?

Tags: http

We've noticed that from time to time we will get a HTTP request without a valid User-Agent string. Is there any valid real-world case for accepting this type of HTTP request?

Why wouldn't we auto block all IP's from which this type of request is received?

**UPDATE**
My intention with the phrase "real-world" was to indicate that I am not asking what the HTTP protocol permits. It is permitted to submit HTTP requests without some headers. I am asking what "real-world" case you would have for allowing this type of HTTP request into your server.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I guess many people use HTTP requests without a User-Agent mostly when they are using an API to perform the request.

Comment: Some bots (e.g. for less-than-mainstream search engines) may not set the user agent string, for example.  Whether you want to accept them or not is entirely up to you.  Normal user requests will almost always have a valid User-Agent (though I have seen people e.g. hack their iPod user agent to something like `Joe's iPod`) and they could  also blank it out.

Comment: The `User-Agent` header is optional in RFC 2616. It *SHOULD* be used by clients, but it is not *REQUIRED* to be used. All of the major third-party browsers/clients use it, but custom apps/APIs/bots/etc might not.  There are webservers that alter responses, or even reject requests (which is annoying), based on the `User-Agent` provided (or lack of one).

Comment: So a "real world" case might be when you are providing an API, and you may not want to require the API users to include a User Agent string.

Comment: Yes, developers rarely make the User-Agent a mandatory field in the HTTP request while developing an API (unless they have a specific use case).

Comment: Btw doesn't adding user agent to every request increased request size unnecessary ?

Comment: @sktguha It likely increases the request size. However, in the context of the entire https request, the size of the user-agent header is negligible compared to, say, the overhead involved in a [TLS session](http://netsekure.org/2010/03/tls-overhead/). Additionally, [hpack](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7541.html) header encoding in HTTP/2 significantly reduces header sizes; for example, this [Cloudflare blog post](https://blog.cloudflare.com/hpack-the-silent-killer-feature-of-http-2/) demonstrates a reduction from 430 bytes to 4 bytes for the cookie and user-agent headers. 1/n

Comment: [continued] Considering the above, and the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.3) "should" recommendation to send a user-agent header, it is generally a good idea to always include the user-agent header in requests. 2/2

Answer (score 32):

As stated in [RFC 7231](http://svn.tools.ietf.org/svn/wg/httpbis/specs/rfc7231.html#rfc.section.5.5.3) (but nearly the same paragraph can be found in [RFC2616](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)):

> 5.5.3 User-Agent
>
> The "User-Agent" header field contains information about the user agent originating the request,
>   which is often used by servers to help identify the scope of reported interoperability problems,
>   to work around or tailor responses to avoid particular user agent limitations, and for analytics
>   regarding browser or operating system use. A user agent SHOULD send a User-Agent field in each
>   request unless specifically configured not to do so.

The keyword here is SHOULD.  And yes, there's an RFC that defines what that word is supposed to mean, [RFC 2119](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt):

> 1. SHOULD   This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there
>      may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a
>      particular item, but the full implications must be understood and
>      carefully weighed before choosing a different course.

So, although the agents that do not send User-Agent do not follow what can be considered best practice, they do not violate any rule (rfc).  So, in my opinion, there's not really a valid *technical* reason to block them.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are some webservers that will reject a request if the `User-Agent` is unknown/unrecognized, which can be annoying. Then you have to provide a custom `User-Agent` that mimics a well-known value that the webserver will accept.

Comment: So your "real world" case where you might want to accept/trust HTTP requests without UserAgent header, is "you might want to allow obscure an bot to use your web site".

Comment: @JulianReschke Thank you for pointing to RFC7231, nice piece of work - I hope you don't mind that I did reintroduce a link to RFC2616 as today it's the one that is the norm.

Comment: fvu: RFC 2616 is obsolete. There's really no point in referencing it anymore, except for historical purposes.

Comment: @Jacob Let me generalize that like this: as de facto blocking these requests would go against [Postel's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) you should accept them unless you detect a strong correlation between types of activity or visitors you don't want on your server.

Answer (score 0):

*From my personal experience*

The requests looks like this in the apache log if no user agent is set:

```
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [10/Sep/2021:07:31:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 25485 "-" "-"
```

This one in specific conducted a malicious act.

I do not recommend blocking automatically but to remain attentive to this type of request.

Answer (score -1):

From my experience, there is not **Legitimate** use case, at least no common one.

From my server logs, all requests without a user agent are malicious. All come from bots.

In theory, someone who "really cares about privacy" could do this. It depends on what service you're providing. I run a couple of websites. People not using browsers are not my clients.

While it's true that it's trivial for a developer of malicious bots to add a user agent (fake one like Chrome), it doesn't mean it's not illegitimate in intention.

Comment: I have built a web app for booking people onto courses. I am logging the user agent so I can decide which browsers to continue to support. Problem is that about 5% of users are not sending back a ua string.  But they are legitimate users because they make bookings and pay for them. Any ideas what browser might return empty ua string?  I am using `var ua = Request.Headers["User-Agent"];`